# Microsoft word any way to select from cursor to the end of file?

Tags: ms-word

I need to delete everything from cursor down to the end of doc. Any way? So far I can only delete use cursor to move down till the end. It is a very big file. And takes too long to get to the bottom. I tried ctrl-end. Would not work.

Comment: ctrl + shift +end then backspace

Comment: Ctrl + End moves the caret to the end of the file. With Shift, you expand the selection to this point instead. (Yes, this is a very general rule.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might help, try **shift + ctrl + end**

Answer (score 1):

FN + CNTRL + SHIFT + END worked for me.

Comment: In Microsoft Windows, you generally press Ctrl+Shift+End to select to the end of the file. You probably have a laptop which requires you to hold FN to access the End key.